# Limit of an expression with exponential function

Tags: limits, exponential-function

I was trying to understand how we can approximate exp.

One example is:

$$ \exp(t) = \sum_{i=0}^\infty t^i/i! $$

however, why is the following true:

$$\lim_{x\to \infty}\exp \left ({\frac{t^2}{2!} +\frac{t^3}{3!\cdot x^{.5}} + \frac{t^4}{4!\cdot x^{1.5}} + \dots } \right) = \exp(\frac{t^2}{2})$$

Comment: what is the *next true*?

Comment: okay, just a second

Comment: $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{t^2}{2!}+\frac{t^3}{3!\sqrt{x}}+...=\frac{t^2}{2!}$

Comment: You are not approximating $\exp(x)$ you are taking the limit $x \to \infty$. You need to show $$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{t^2}{2!}+\frac{t^3}{3!x^{0.5}}+\dots=\frac{t^2}{2!}$$

Comment: I was trying to connect the Taylors expansion with this problem

Comment: Take $\log$ on both sides.

Answer (score 0):

(Hint) First, as experimentX suggest, take the log of both sides to get rid of $\exp$ (you can pull $\exp$ out of the limit because $\exp$ is a continuous function).  Now since $t$ is fixed, you can treat it as constant in the limit.
What happens to a term like $\displaystyle \frac{t^3}{3!x^{.5}}$ as $x \to \infty$?